# What's the max size limit of partition and value in ignite

Tags: ignite

I need to put some big data in Ignite using Key-Value API, let's say at least 128 MB, I wonder what's the max size of a value in cache, and what's the max size of a partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition size doesn't have any kind of limit.

When you are feeding large entries into Ignite there is only one strict limitation — a single entry must be less than WAL segment size. It's defaulted to 64mb, so you must increase it to let yor use-case work.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/native-persistence#changing-wal-segment-size